# Unrecognized Type: for length of date string

Tags: bash, shell, osx

I am getting current date and checking for length of date if non-zero then perform some action.

```
now=$(date)
echo "$now"
if [[ -n "$now" ]]; then
echo "not empty"
fi
```

Prints this to console-

```
Mon Feb 17 01:51:38 CST 2014
Unrecognized Type: Mon
not empty
```

*if [[ -n "$now" ]]; then* -> this line is causing shell to throw Unrecognized Type: warning, Is there something wrong with the check -n ?

Comment: my bash on Linux doesn't give that "unrecognized Type" message. Any reason not to sue `if [ -n "$now" ] ; then`?

Comment: @Anthon, if it were a `bash` error, we'd see `bash: line x: Unrecognized type...`.

Comment: Are you sure it's `bash` that interprets that code. What's the output of `sed -n l < that-script`?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I should have written that running that piece of code using `bash` (as implied from the OP's tags) did not generate that message.

Comment: Tried if [ -n "$now" ]; then, same error without line #. Tried both - bash, bourne shells. Interesting thing is that if condition is executed, despite throwing that Unrecognized type: warning onto console.

Comment: You mean you have those 5 lines in `a-script`, and run `bash ./a-script` and get that error message? Again, can you please give the output of `sed -n l < a-script`?

Answer (score 2):

`[[` is a (e.g.) bash feature. Use this instead:

```
if [ -n "$now" ]; then
```